# BigQuery ML K-means with new data dataset after the trained model

Tags: google-bigquery

I understand that K-means clustering is an unsupervised learning modeling technique, typically used for such segmentation.
Once I have trained and created the model with the data set in BigQuery ML using K-means clustering, so I have a question if it is possible to perform the prediction on this same model with another new data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You'll have your [model stored in your dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#step_three_create_a_k-means_model) and you can use the [ML.PREDICT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#use_ml.predict) function with different data by using your model.

Hope it helps.